Axios Promise.allSettled doesn't work in parallel in Chrome
I have this parallel request mechanism in a ReactJS project. I followed the online sources while implementing this. I gather the promises in an array than feed it to allSettled then collect the result.
let promises = [];

for (const [_, value] of values) {
    promises.push(axios.get(`https://url`, {
        timeout: 5000,
        signal: AbortSignal.timeout(5000), //Aborts request after 5 seconds
        headers: {"val": value}
    }));
}

const result = await Promise.allSettled(promises)

My problem is that, in firefox this executes perfectly. However in Chrome, all the requests happen one by one(not parallel), so it is very slow and eventually timeout because of the 5 second limit I've put in.
Another interesting this is, if I open network tab and select "disable cache", in Chrome, there requests happen in parallel and work the way they are supposed to.
What could be the reason for this?
axios version: 1.4.0
Chrome version: 122.0.6261.128
Node version: 18.2
Edit: While trying to simplify the code, apparently I've excluded the part that caused this, now edited, please check the code again. (Request is same URL, with varying headers)
Edit2: Found this. Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?
It's easier to find info now I know what I am looking for.
Edit3:

İt looks like requests are waiting each other, even though the promise executor has been run. And it is a request to the same origin.

Sounds like it might be a bug in chrome, although I wouldn't file that on the tracker unless I was very sure.

You make all requests to the same URL https://url? Also, my browser cannot resolve this hostname.

@JaredSmith Not very experienced with JS, so i was actually convinced I did something wrong.

@HeikoTheißen url is of course an invalid URL. it is a placeholder for my api. Its a request to the same domain with different headers if important.

And you may well have, but the cache empty vs not difference in behavior sounds... weird to say the least.

@MaxPaython - The code shown seems fine. (I'd've used map rather than the loop, but the loop is fine.) I suspect a session cookie or some other similar thing causing the requests to be serialized. Very, very unlikely to be a bug in Chrome. Can you provide more detail about the request happening "one by one"? If you watch the Network tab in devtools, do they all start and then only finish one at a time? Or do you see only one request start, then finish, then the next request start? (I would find that second possibility very hard to believe, but I have to ask. :-) )

@MaxPaython - Separately, what does the server side of this look like? I think that's the side that's more likely to be causing it (despite the Firefox vs. Chrome thing), but...

What does the Node version have to do with a question about chrome? You should probably give us the version of your chrome instead

@T.J.Crowder Actually the disable cache thing gave me an idea, I added a cachebuster query string to the url. And the requests happened in parallel. It seems like chrome locks the requests to the same url. And firefox doesnt.

@derpirscher Chrome is (122.0.6261.128), I shared node version because I don't have the experience in the subject to make the decision to exclude it's relevance.

@MaxPaython - "It seems like chrome locks the requests to the same url." But only when cache is empty? That doesn't make sense. It's true that browsers have limits on concurrent requests to the same resource (and to the same server, even different resources), but I thought the lowest limit was 2, and I can't imagine what clearing cache or not would have to do with that.

Update Chrome to the current version (124.0.6367), it's probably a bug that is now fixed ... In general I find if it works in Firefox but not in Chrome, it's a Chrome issue (i.e a bug that will get fixed in the next release, when a new bug will be introduced). If it works in Chrome but not in Firefox, it's usually some "new thing" that Chrome has implemented but Firefox has not yet implemented.

@MaxPaython - In addition to my earlier question, is the request to a same-origin or cross-origin URL?

@T.J.Crowder Thanks for your time and interest. I answered it in the third edit in the question.

@MaxPaython - Thanks! That's what I thought was happening. (You're doing great debugging!  So often people don't.) How many elements in values? Also, just FYI re "...even though the promise executor has been run..." since you said you're not very experienced with JavaScript: It doesn't matter what you've done with the promises, the loop making the requests is synchronous and starts the requests one after another. The promises are just a way of telling your code what happens with the requests, they don't cause the requests to happen. The call to axios.get does that bit. :-)

@T.J.Crowder There are around 60 elements.

@MaxPaython - I can replicate what you're seeing locally (with really simple server code: https://pastebin.com/75vKqv3Q), with one diff: For me, it doesn't matter whether cache has been cleared or not. What matters is that the requests are to the same URL. But, if I disable cache (by having the Network tools open and ticking the "Disable cache" box), it goes away, and I see six concurrent requests at a time (which is Chrome's per-origin concurrent limit). That suggests to me that you've found your answer in...

...the 2014 question you linked, which says this is something Chrome does for cache management. Do you agree? It looks like that behavior hasn't changed since then.

@T.J.Crowder Yes, it looks like a design choice by Google. I've seen other issues with browser cache happen when same URL used with different request headers to get a different response. I just didn't think of that this cache would have a lock around it, even though almost all caching mechanisms do have this :) In the end I ended up using a counter as a cachebuster qs, but i could just transfer the value in the header to the qs and adjust my server to handle it that way. Chrome's behavior may improve my http client design after all :)

@MaxPaython - Thank you for the question (which taught me something and I suspect I'm not the only one), the debugging, responding to comments, etc. Great stuff and I'm sure it will help many others. :-)
